# how to avoid hardcoding an input file name in php ? and upload it later?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have created a PHP web page, and in that i am reading the contents from an input text file, and posting the contents onto the web page, as shown below:

```
<? PHP
   $filename = 'txt.txt';
   $str = file_get_contents($filename);
   $data = explode("\n", $str);
   -----
 ?>
```

but i don't want to hardcode this filename and provide it or upload it later, after loading the web page,
i could read the filename and print it as follows,

```
<label for="file">Filename:</label>
<input type="file" name ="file" onchange = "FileLoad(this.value)" >

<script>
    function FileLoad(val) {
       var jk = val ;
      alert(jk) ;
       }
 </script>
```

but how to provide this filename to $filename variable in php ?

Comment: Why do you need the PHP in that script at all - can't you load and process it with pure JS?

Comment: Post it to your PHP file?